# 404 error CSS file not found in chrome dev tools

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-app-engine, jinja2

I've spent an hour and a half reading other posts about this issue and still haven't solved it. I believe the file is in the right place and the file path reference is the appropriate one. I'm testing my web application locally trying to style it up a bit and chrome dev tools is saying that the CSS file cannot be found. I'm using Python, Google App Engine and Jinja2. [Check out the error](http://chorestimemadison.appspot.com/) for yourself if you'd like. Thanks in advance for your time and expertise!

Here are my HTML files. The second one inherits from the first one.

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Chores</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <a href="/" class="main-title">
    Chores
  </a>

  <div id="content">
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**front.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="/dochore">Do Chore</a>
  &nbsp;
  <a href="/addchore"> + Add Chore</a>
  &nbsp;
  <a href="/removechore"> - Remove Chore</a>
  &nbsp;
  <a href="/choredetail">Chore Details</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  {% for chore in chores %}
    {{ chore.render() | safe }}
    <br><br>
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

My project directory is structured like...

```
project-name/
  main.py
  templates/
    HTML files
  static/
    style.css
```

Here's my app.yaml...

```
application: chorestimemadison
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Comment: Can you post your app.yaml handlers? Seems to me the static directory might not be correctly setup.

Comment: Follow-up question to add some details to my answer: Are you using Apache, nginx, or IIS?

Comment: @JoshuaWhitley I'm not using any of those three technologies you just mentioned.

Comment: @JulianDavid What web server are you using? And are you *positive* that the root directory for this website is set to /project-name? Because this is *definitely* an access/permissions issue.

Comment: @JoshuaWhitley I'm using google app engine for python. Hmm, well the project folder is sitting inside of a folder on my desktop. e.g. desktop > some_folder > project_folder

Comment: I believe your static directory is not correctly setup, please post the app.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a handler for the static directory:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

[Learn more about why this is necessary.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles)

Comment: I thought this would fix it, but it didn't :(

Comment: Then there's some other problem. It's fairly early in development for you so why not try to do the [linked] tutorial, step by step, should only take a few minutes and by the end you'll have everything properly setup :)

Comment: Nailed it! So apparently, order matters because I had the static url listed after the main url in my app.yaml and it didn't work, but once I switched it to have the static one first, it worked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting you're having an issue with directory access. If your HTML files are under the templates folder and your templates folder is the location that's being served as http://chorestimemadison.appspot.com/, then the HTML files cannot access the static folder (or the CSS files therein) no matter what URL you use because they're not part of the web server's directory structure.

You'll have to either:

1. Move the static folder into the templates folder.
2. Change the root directory of your web server to be project-name instead of templates and change the reference to style.css to `../static/style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

As your css and html files are in paralel folders you first need to back off 1 directory with "../" and then type your css path like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

The way you typed, it's looking for your css in templates/static, because tempalates is your current folder (where the html executes)

Comment: He can't go up a level because the html file that is being served is at the root of his virtual directory structure. See my answer for details.

Comment: It's not the roof as the roof is project-name and both templates and static are subdirectories

Comment: Ivan, I have already tried that and unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: Can you move your "static" folder into the "templates" one just to see that you can actually access this css file ? also add "./" when you link to files like href="./static/style.css". It's a good practice

Answer (score 0):

Use "./" instead of "/". It helps to get the current directory.
In your case, the code should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/style.css" type="text/css" />
```